# Can I give hints to the list operator(%) for memory allocation in Boost.Spirit.Qi?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit-qi

I want to parse the following data list.

```
N; data1, data2 .... dataN;

example: "100000; 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... 100000;" (A very large list)
```

Simple parsing:

```
auto rule = qi::int_ >> qi::lit(';') >> qi::int_ % ',' >> qi::lit(';');
```

However, in this case, I think that log2 (N) times memory reallocation occurs according to the specification of `std::vector`.

I think that this can be avoided by the following method.

```
int size;
std::vector<int> v;
qi::phrase_parse(itr, end, qi::int_ >> qi::lit(';'), qi::space, size);
v.reserve(size); // reserve memory
qi::phrase_parse(itr, end, qi::int_ % ',' >> qi::lit(';'), qi::space, v);
```

Is there a way to give hints on memory allocation for vectors on a single rule like this? For example, it is like `qi::repeat(N)`.　Or is there a technique to avoid reallocating vector memory?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can reserve in an action.

Better yet, do it in an epsilon argument so that you don't lose automatic attribute propagation.

Proof of concept: **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dcad15e95a70e6ed)</kbd>**

**Updated**: Extended the demo. It turns out Phoenix already has functors for `reserve` and `capacity`, as well as `size`.

Note that

- now the reserve is a *semantic action*,
- the rule uses `%=` to enable automatic attribute propagation still,
- and then (ironically?) uses `qi::omit` to prevent from inserting the first `int_` attribute into the container as well

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63a587deef019e35)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace px = boost::phoenix;

int main() {
    using Attr = std::vector<int>;
    using It   = std::string::const_iterator;

    qi::rule<It, Attr(), qi::space_type> rule;

    rule %= qi::omit[qi::int_ [ px::reserve(qi::_val, qi::_1) ] >> ';' ]
         >> (qi::eps(px::size(qi::_val) < px::capacity(qi::_val)) >> qi::int_) % ','
         >> ';'
         ;

    for (std::string const input : { 
            "42; 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41;", })
    {
        It f = begin(input), l = end(input);
        Attr data;
        std::cout << "Capacity before: " << data.capacity() << "\n";

        if (phrase_parse(f, l, rule, qi::space, data))
            std::cout << "Parsed: " << data.size() << " elements ";
        else
            std::cout << "Parse failed at '" << std::string(f,l) << "' ";

        if (f != l)
            std::cout << "Remaining: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'";
        std::cout << '\n';

        std::cout << "Capacity after: " << data.capacity() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Capacity before: 0
Parsed: 42 elements 
Capacity after: 42
```

Comment: Extended [the demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63a587deef019e35) (turns out Phoenix already has functors for `reserve` and `capacity`, as well as `size`). Note that now the reserve is a _semantic action_, the rule uses `%=` to enable automatic attribute propagation still, and then (ironically?) uses `qi::omit` to prevent from inserting the first `int_` attribute into the container as well :)